# Merge Pandas Dataframes on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames I am trying to merge using pandas.

```
lu_3
Site    SurveyDate  TripDate
003L    1990-09-28  1990-06-10
065r    2008-04-03  2008-03-28

data
Site    SurveyDate  
003L    1990-09-28  
065r    2008-04-03
```

I am trying to merge `lu_3` to populate `data` with a `TripDate`.  `data` has been subsetted for ease of reading, but contains more columns than shown.  Both data frames are using `Site` as the index.

I have tried:

```
tmp = data.merge(lu_3,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left', on=['SurveyDate'])
```

But that returns a `NaT` for the trip date.

Checking the data types yields:

```
lu_3.dtypes
Out[111]: 
SurveyDate    datetime64[ns]
TripDate      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

data.dtypes
Out[114]: 
SurveyDate        datetime64[ns]
```

**EDIT**

I have reset the indicies on `data` and `lu_3` and tried to merge using:

```
tmp = tmp_data.merge(lu_3,on=['Site','SurveyDate'], how='left').set_index('Site')
```

But I am still getting `NaT` for `TripDate` on `tmp`.

Comment: check the date type of `SurveyDate` in both dataframes to ensure that they are consistent, eg. `Type(data.SurveryDate)`

Comment: They are both `pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: Sorry, `Type(data.SurveryDate.iat[0])`  will get the type of the first element in the series.

Comment: That returns `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` for both

Comment: It worked for me. Which version of Pandas are you using?  0.18.0 is latest.

Comment: I have 0.17.1.  I will update and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to specify on when you are merging on index

```
tmp = data.merge(lu_3,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left')

         SurveyDate_x SurveyDate_y    TripDate
Site                                      
003L   1990-09-28   1990-09-28  1990-06-10
065r   2008-04-03   2008-04-03  2008-03-28
```